# How can find the port of SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: database

The default port is 1433, but somebody changed it in my hosting, how can find the port used by  SQL Server 2008 Express ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL` find the name of your express instance. For example let it be MSSQL@YOUREXPRESSNAME
- Open registry Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL@YOUREXPRESSNAME\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp`
- Look inside any IP in list to find the proper port

**OR**

open Sql Server config manager and look inside Network Protocols

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to change by giong to SQL server configuration manager.